# Best Practice: spending transactions to expense list

Tags: list-manipulation, coding-style

So lets say I have a list of spending transactions `tlist = {{john,23},{bob,2},{john,7}...}` and I want to have a list of the total expenses per person.

I can do this procedurally by iterating over the transactions in tlist using a for loop. If their name is not yet in the expense list, I add it as a row, with the corresponding spending. If their name is in the expense list, I add the transaction amount to their total.

This is fine, but I am aware that for loops are frowned upon in Mathematica, and are relatively inefficient. So, what would be the proper, "good code" way of doing this?

Comment: `Dataset[Total /@ GroupBy[tlist, First -> Last]]`

Comment: Also `Dataset@GroupBy[tlist, First -> Last, Total]`

Answer (score 8):

[GroupBy](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) is very helpful function for exploring data. This answer is an extension of Bob Hanlon's comment where more structure has been added to the sample data.

First, some random names

```
names = WolframAlpha[ToString[100] <> " random surnames", {{"Result", 1},"ComputableData"}];
```

Then a modified list

```
tlist =  Table[<|"name" -> RandomChoice[names], 
"expense" -> RandomReal[{1, 1000}], 
"age" -> RandomReal[{23, 56}]|>, {i, 1, 10000}];
```

Then to find the total expense for each person

```
res = GroupBy[tlist, #["name"] &, Total[#[[All, {"expense"}]]] &]
```

and to format the output

```
Dataset[res]
```

[image: Example output]

Comment: +1 You might also want to sort: `Manipulate[
 Dataset[res] // SortBy[#, sort] &,
 {{sort, "name", "Sort By"}, {"name", "expense"}}]`